# how to use external interrupts on GPIO beaglebone

Tags: embedded-linux, interrupt-handling, gpio, beagleboneblack

I am looking to enable external interrupt on the rising and falling edge of a GPIO pin configured as input on Beagle Bone. How do I go about doing this? I know how to use GPIO's using the /sys/class/gpio and /dev/mem method. Can anyone tell me what piece of code do I need to write to make the code jump to an interrupt handler on a certain input event on the gpio pin?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of latency can you tolerate?  Were you planning to have the handling code in userspace or kernelspace?

Comment: I need low latency, although, could you guide me for either.

Comment: What is your application?  What are your constraints?

Comment: i am looking to use the GPIO pins for flow control for a SPI bus between beaglebone and a 32 bit Atmel uC. I am using a gpio pin through the /dev/mem method to transmit commands from the beaglebone(master) to the uC(slave) at high speeds and would like to implement ISR to perform certain tasks based on certain commands from the slave.

Comment: If you are trying to write an interrupt driven bit-bang SPI driver, that will almost certainly need to be in the kernel, with only the sent/received message bytes exposed to userspace.  Try to find an example of a driver for an interrupt-based peripheral on your hardware.

Comment: if I am to make a very simple program that calls an ISR say - buttonEvent on the press of a button which in turn toggles an led. How would i go about doing that?

Comment: For something with a loose human-scale latency tolerance like that, you would do it in userspace, using one of the interrupt gpio devices where a read blocks until the condition is met.  But that's *very* different from your SPI case.

Comment: would writing a module to register and use interrupts on GPIO pins work?

Comment: Here I do that using epoll: https://github.com/nachiketkulkarni/AntzBBB/blob/master/AntzBBB/src/utils/communication/ir/receiver.c